# How to add a new dimension in a numpy matrix

Tags: numpy-ndarray

I have two matrices:

```
array([[2, 3],
       [2, 4],
       [2, 5]])
```

```
array([[1, 13],
       [1, 14],
       [1, 15]])
```

how do I merge them to get:

```
array([[[2, 3],[1, 13]],
       [[2, 4],[1, 14]],
       [[2, 5], [1, 15]]])
```

without writing a for loop, 
I have checked `np.hstack, np.stack` but none of those functions yield the result I want..

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a late answer but if you still need it:

```
np.hstack((a, b)).reshape((3, 2, 2))
>>> array([[[ 2,  3],
            [ 1, 13]],

           [[ 2,  4],
            [ 1, 14]],

           [[ 2,  5],
            [ 1, 15]]])
```